# How does firebase actually decide a userbase for doing AB testing?

Tags: android, ab-testing, firebase-ab-testing

I am learning ab testing for android apps. I have integrated firebase sdk into my android app and also setup remote config (need to ab test on colors of buttons within my app) . So i have two variants , one is the baseline and another a variant.
I have started the experiment, now how do i get users to download my app?
Do i have to put my app on the google play store or are there some testers provided by firebase itself?

I am a newbie in this field. Could anyone please guide me on how firebase ab testing works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZVjd.png)
I have done the integration part of firebase with my app and also the AB testing part. How do i proceed from here?